# Too few parameters on insert statement

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, parameters, insert

Hi I am attempting an insert statement but keep getting the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too
>   few parameters. Expected 3.

Here is my code:

```
 try {

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    String mySqlStatement = "INSERT INTO EntrantDetails (ID, Name, Surname, Gender, DOB ChipNum) VALUES (" + details.getIDNum()+ "," + details.getName() + "," + details.getSurname() + "," + details.getGender() + "," + details.getDOB() +  "," + details.getChipNum() + ")";
    stmt.executeUpdate(mySqlStatement);       
    }

     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: Presumably  details.getName() returns a string? If so it should be 'quoted' (and escaped)

Comment: Off topic , but Start using a `PreparedStatement` !

Comment: Also is DOB ChipNum one field or is there missing comma. If it is one field is this correct representation or should there be [] around it ???

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma between DOB and ChipNum. Pay a little attention to what you're writing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you supposed to have a comma between DOB and ChipNum?

Answer (score 0):

DOB and chipnum are two separate fields I suppose. If so, they have to be separated by a comma.